# Google Analytics time delay in events report

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using `Google Analytics` in an Android Application. I have registered few events using `EventBuilder`. For me it took almost a day to show that events in `Google Analytics` web portal. But in `iOS` it shows the event builder hits within 10 to 15 minutes of time. How its happening? Am I missing anything?

**EDIT** I'm not talking about `RealTime` tracker. In that we can see the traffics and locations. I'm talking about `Events`.

Answer (score 2):

### Dispatch settings

There are different default settings for Android and iOS. It sends event in batch mode once time in 30 minutes (or different time frame).

Check out documentation
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch?hl=cs

### Website usage

Time required for data processing depends on amount of hits sended to UA account. Full data-processing usually tooks between 4 hours to 1 day. So you don't miss anything.

Some data are accessible faster, like events, default dimensions, etc., but custom dimensions and dimension breakdowns tooks longer time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I was doing a silly mistake while viewing report. By default `Analytics` will be show data till yesterday. By changing the date to today at `Right top corner` in portal displayed today's events. Minimum time it took to display the data is 15 to 30 minutes. May be it might vary depends on the number of hits.